# Best method to optimize performance of FlatList Items

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

This a simple FlatList:

```
class Products ..
render() {
    return (
          <FlatList
          renderItem={this._renderItem}
           );
}
```

I want to create a list of items and navigate to Detail Page by onPress items.

Can Please tell me which method is better?

**Method 1:**

Insert navigate to Detail page in child component(`CardProduct` component) like this:

```
_renderItem = ({item}) => (

    <CardProduct
      id={item.id}
      title={item.title}
    />
  );
```

and in CardProduct component:

```
render() {
    const { id,title } = this.props;

    return (
      <Card style={{flex:1}}>
          <CardItem cardBody button onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Details',{productId:id})}>
          ...
    );
}
```

**Method 2:**

Insert navigate to Detail page in current component(`Products` component) like this:

```
_onPressItem = (id: string) => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Details',{productId:id});
};

_renderItem = ({item}) => (

    <CardProduct
      id={item.id}
      title={item.title}
      onPressItem={this._onPressItem}
    />
  );
```

and in CardProduct component:

```
_onPress = () => {
    this.props.onPressItem(this.props.id);
};

render() {
    const { id,title } = this.props;

    return (
      <Card style={{flex:1}}>
          <CardItem cardBody button onPress={this._onPress}>
          ...
    );
}
```

I used to do the method 1, but I read [this guide](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short answer:

You should go for method2.

### Explanation:

In **method1** you are using an arrow function in `CardItem's` onPress, so everytime `CardProduct` is re-rendered a new reference of onPress is created, which forces CardItem to re-render, even if all the other props are staying the same. In **method 2** you are binding the function to context, which won't force a re-rendering of the `CardItem`.

By the way, in general it is a good idea to prevent the usage of arrow functions in `render()`.

Answer (score 0):

One step for performance optimization in react-native flatlist, is using a stateless functional component for the renderItem. and you should always give each item a unique key.